# How to optimize this moving average calculation, in F#

Tags: f#

I have a moving average that has the following particularities:

- Each entry has a timestamp, the values are not evenly distributed in time and the queue length can vary significantly.
- I do not have a fixed period, so the code must be flexible as several periods will be requested.
- The period used is a timestamp and only records above that timestamp are to be used.

This is the code:

```
module PriceMovingAverage =

    // queue duration
    let queueDuration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1.)

    // moving average queue
    let private timestampQueue = Queue<DateTime>()
    let private priceQueue     = Queue<float>()

    // update moving average
    let updateMovingAverage (tradeData: TradeData) =

        // add the new price
        timestampQueue.Enqueue(tradeData.Timestamp)
        priceQueue.Enqueue(float tradeData.Price)

        // remove the items older than the price base period
        let rec dequeueLoop () =
            if timestampQueue.Peek() + queueDuration < tradeData.Timestamp then
                timestampQueue.Dequeue() |> ignore
                priceQueue.Dequeue() |> ignore
                dequeueLoop()

        dequeueLoop()


    // get the moving average
    let getPrice fromTimestamp =

        // count how many records to skip
        let recordsToSkip =
            timestampQueue
            |> Seq.takeWhile (fun t -> t < fromTimestamp)
            |> Seq.length

        // calculate the average of the prices within the time range
        try
            Some (
                priceQueue
                |> Seq.skip recordsToSkip
                |> Seq.average
                |> decimal
            )
        with _ ->
            None
```

The issue is the last part:
I'm iterating through the timestamp queue to find how many records I need to skip. Then I'm going through the price records to calculate the average.

A lot of the CPU time is spent on the first part:

```
let recordsToSkip =
        timestampQueue
        |> Seq.takeWhile (fun t -> t < fromTimestamp)
        |> Seq.length
```

going through the sequence and then calculating the length is slow.

Ideally, I'd just use an array with a circular buffer, but the problem is that the length of the queue can vary significantly based on the data as the index is really the timestamp and not the position in the queue.

I could turn this into a list instead of a sequence and maybe gain some speed, but that means copying the whole list each time.
I assumed it would be faster to have two queues in order to do the average, but maybe this is not true.

Does anyone have an idea how to make this fast (it's called 5-10x / sec) while keeping the flexibility?

---

Edit:

Merging the two queues yields this:

```
   let getPrice fromTimestamp =
        try
            Some (
                priceQueue
                |> Seq.toList
                |> List.skipWhile (fun t -> t.Timestamp < fromTimestamp)
                |> List.averageBy (fun t -> t.Price)
                |> decimal
            )
        with _ ->
            None
```

It's faster, but it's still super slow.

---

Edit:

- I made a Jupyter notebook here: https://pastebin.com/E3uS6j7T
- If you prefer, I also pasted test code directly here: https://pastebin.com/fK18Wyui

Comment: Can you add your type definition & some code to generate sample data, so that people can actually run the code when trying to answer? I don't think I can give any hints without being able to run this, but I'd be happy to play with it, if I can!

Comment: @TomasPetricek, I have added both a Jupyter notebook and the code itself on pastebin, in the edited post. For some reason, I couldn't do a Fiddle, it wouldn't compile the List.skipWhile

Comment: @Thomas Then I guess the fiddle is using an old version of F#. There was a version where all functions for all collections got harmonized... maybe 2 years ago.

Comment: Just for the giggles - how fast is it if you turn the list you have at call time into an array first, then do the binary search, then the average computation? Intuition sometimes makes us dismiss possible approaches... also... I think the Timestamp you use is a reference object... if you turned it into some uint64 instead... that might help, too (increasing locality of data).

Comment: without changing anything else (still linear search on timestamps), doing a Seq.toArray and using array functions brings the time down to 252 seconds, vs 280 with the List.skipWhile and 319 with the seq.filter

Comment: I just checked, DateTime is a value type, so no optimization there; but yes, the binary search seems like the next optimization, but the problem is that the timestamp used in the parameter may not exist in the list since I need to take values larger than the parameter, maybe none are equal to it.

Comment: Once you have an array, you could also go multi core... also I wonder if the timestamp compare function is as fast as a uint64 compare... It depends on how it is implemented.

Comment: but the binary sort function does equality only, right?

Comment: I have done more testing: having the type with the time / value as a struct yields a small speedup; but the biggest difference has been with going back to 2 queues: one with time and one with the value and just dequeuing to keep the right number of values in the queue; then I need a pricequeue |> Seq.average and this is still taking quite long to process (roughly 40% of the app's cpu time in that loop is that Seq.average call). So I guess the issue is dealing with the Seq. Converting it to an array beforehand is even slower.

Comment: http://www.eckner.com/research.html  - Look in Algorithms for Unevenly Spaced Time Series.

Comment: @BentTranberg, I will definitely go through that! thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, it's like [Asti says in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64286205). On the other, if you absolutely must keep your data in two separate queues, you can enumerate them in one pass with `Seq.zip`:

```
timestampQueue.Enqueue <| DateTime.Parse("2020-10-08T17:30"); priceQueue.Enqueue 100.
timestampQueue.Enqueue <| DateTime.Parse("2020-10-08T18:00"); priceQueue.Enqueue 110.
timestampQueue.Enqueue <| DateTime.Parse("2020-10-08T18:30"); priceQueue.Enqueue 120.
timestampQueue.Enqueue <| DateTime.Parse("2020-10-08T19:00"); priceQueue.Enqueue 130.

Seq.zip timestampQueue priceQueue
|> Seq.filter (fun (t, _) -> t >= DateTime.Parse("2020-10-08T18:00"))
|> Seq.averageBy snd
(* val it : float = 120.0 *)
```

Comment: the data doesn't have to be in separate queues; I made it that way because I assumed that once I knew how many records to skip, the average would be faster. It turns out it's not the case (see 1st edit to the question). I will check the filter / averageBy method to see how it compares performance wise (but with the timestamp / price in one object)

Comment: ...or use `Seq.skipWhile` as well. I would try to avoid anything involving `Seq.skip`.

Comment: benchmark is running right now, I'll report in a few minutes :)

Comment: it is slower than the last method I posted in the question; with my test data, I get 319 sec with the filter vs. 280 sec

Answer (score 2):

While I am not sure, how many queue entries you have if you call it 5-10 times per second... I tested the code below with 1E6 entries and it was blazingly fast.

The code just addresses the "skip" part of the problem, which appears to be the main issue in the question. The code is using (hand crafted) binary search on an array, returning the matching index or the index after, if there is no match.

```ml
module MovingAverage

let  N = 1000000

let inline findFirstIndexAbove target a =
    let upper = Array.length a
    let rec  loop lower upper =
        let mid = lower + (upper - lower) / 2
        //printfn "lower = %d, mid = %d, upper = %d" lower mid upper
        if mid = lower
        then
            if a.[mid] = target
            then mid
            else upper
        else
            if a.[mid] < target
            then
                loop mid upper
            else if a.[mid] > target
            then loop lower mid
            else mid
    loop 0 upper

let test1 () =
    let ats = Array.init N (fun _ -> System.DateTime.Now)
    findFirstIndexAbove (ats.[10]) ats

let test2 () =
    let au64 = Array.init N (fun i -> 2UL * uint64 i)
    findFirstIndexAbove (au64.[10]+1UL) au64
```

And on my machine (Debian 64 bit, cheap AMD cpu, using `dotnet fsi` as interactive shell (not fsharpi!), I get the following timings for `test1()` and `test2()` respectively.

> test1 ();;
> Real: 00:00:00.223, CPU: 00:00:00.220, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : int = 10
> test2 ();;
> Real: 00:00:00.005, CPU: 00:00:00.000, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : int = 11

The majority of the time spent in test1() is the initialization of the array with the time stamps.

With the above as a recipe, here the rather counter-intuitive array approach in a scenario closer to the question:

```ml
[<Struct>]
type TradeData =
    {
        timeStamp : System.DateTime
        price : float 
    }

let inline skipBeyondOldData target a =
    let upper = Array.length a
    let rec  loop lower upper =
        let mid = lower + (upper - lower) / 2
        //printfn "lower = %d, mid = %d, upper = %d" lower mid upper
        if mid = lower
        then
            if a.[mid].timeStamp = target
            then mid
            else upper
        else
            if a.[mid].timeStamp < target
            then
                loop mid upper
            else if a.[mid].timeStamp > target
            then loop lower mid
            else mid
    loop 0 upper

let oneHour = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0)

let cyclicUpdate state (currentPrice : TradeData) =
    let tnow = System.DateTime.Now;
    let tstart = tnow - oneHour
    let workingSetStartIndex = skipBeyondOldData tstart state
    let state1 = Array.append (state.[workingSetStartIndex..]) [| currentPrice |]
    let avgPrice = Array.averageBy (fun td -> td.price) state1
    (avgPrice,state1)

let rng = System.Random()

let initialState = Array.init N (fun _ -> { timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now; price = rng.NextDouble(); })
```

With the resulting timing:

> cyclicUpdate initialState { timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now; price = rng.NextDouble() };;
> Real: 00:00:00.016, CPU: 00:00:00.010, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0
> val it : float * TradeData [] = (0.5001679869, ... )

Comment: Is there a specific reason you didn't want to use `Array.BinarySearch`?

Comment: @Asti not really. I just wanted to see the code I use since obviously the author of the question ran into something... so I tried to keep the unknowns to a minimum.

Comment: @Asti Another post-mortem reason is that I use dotnet core and the array module does not seem to have BinarySearch... https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-arraymodule.html

Comment: I added a comment to the question: it looks like Seq.average is taking the bulk of the time if I keep the queue to the size of the data I need; it's faster to have multiple queue with different lengths than trying to get the data I need. But unfortunately, iterating the sequence is very slow

Answer (score 1):

The `skip` is costly, both for `seq` and `list`.
For a large number of items, `list` is not an optimal choice because of cache misses.

Use a single type like `Timestamped<T>` to capture both the timestamp and the value. Use a `List<T>` instead of a queue, or ideally a circular buffer. It looks like the timestamps are added in chronological order, so in place of `skipWhile`, use [List.BinarySearch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netcore-3.1) to locate the lower bound as fast as possible.

Additionally you can amortize the cost of queries by pre-computing the averages for a block of k data points, and then computing the average of those +/- the points which lie outside of each block.

Comment: but the Queue<T> is part of the BCL, isn't it? it's not F# specific, but I guess it's still implemented as a linked list no matter what. You're right that the timestamps are chronological, so the search could be optimized.