# How to implement a time based length queue in F#?

Tags: optimization, f#

This is a followup to question: [How to optimize this moving average calculation, in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284886/how-to-optimize-this-moving-average-calculation-in-f/64287866#64287866)

To summarize the original question: I need to make a moving average of a set of data I collect; each data point has a timestamp and I need to process data up to a certain timestamp.
This means that I have a list of variable size to average.

The original question has the implementation as a queue where elements gets added and eventually removed as they get too old.
But, in the end, iterating through a queue to make the average is slow.

Originally the bulk of the CPU time was spent finding the data to average, but then once this problem was removed by only keeping the data needed in the first place, the Seq.average call proved to be very slow.

It looks like the original mechanism (based on Queue<>) is not appropriate and this question is about finding a new one.

I can think of two solutions:

- implement this as a circular buffer which is large enough to accommodate the worst case scenario, this would allow to use an array and do only two iterations to make the sum.
- quantize the data in buckets and pre-sum it, but I'm not sure if the extra complexity will help performance.

Is there any implementation of a circular buffer that would behave similarly to a Queue<>?

The fastest code, so far, is:

```
module PriceMovingAverage =

    // moving average queue
    let private timeQueue  = Queue<DateTime>()
    let private priceQueue = Queue<float>()

    // update moving average
    let updateMovingAverage (tradeData: TradeData) priceBasePeriod =

        // add the new price
        timeQueue.Enqueue(tradeData.Timestamp)
        priceQueue.Enqueue(float tradeData.Price)

        // remove the items older than the price base period
        let removeOlderThan = tradeData.Timestamp - priceBasePeriod
        let rec dequeueLoop () =
            let p = timeQueue.Peek()
            if p < removeOlderThan then
                timeQueue.Dequeue() |> ignore
                priceQueue.Dequeue() |> ignore
                dequeueLoop()

        dequeueLoop()


    // get the moving average
    let getPrice () =
        try
            Some (
                priceQueue
                |> Seq.average   <- all CPU time goes here
                |> decimal
            )
        with _ ->
            None
```

Comment: How many items are typically in the Queue?

Comment: typically the queue holds about 1h of data and there are 3-4 events / sec in average, so I'd say 10-15k. I'm questioning the speed of a raw optimized piece of code going over an array vs. the overhead of having pre-computer bins, or the overhead of doing it in parallel.

Comment: What kind of time granularity do you need?  You can get a finite length by turning events[]/sec -> (sum, count).  That'd turn 10-15k events into 3.6k buckets.  5s (720 buckets), 15s (240), or even 1m (60) seems p easy and to code and compute.

Comment: That’s what I’ve done to test. I made 10s buckets and the speed has gone up tremendously but I’m still trying to assess if the precision is enough

Answer (score 0):

Based on a queue length of 10-15k I'd say there's definitely scope to consider batching trades into precomputed blocks of maybe around 100 trades.

Add a few types:

```
type TradeBlock = {
    data: TradeData array
    startTime: DateTime
    endTime: DateTime
    sum: float
    count:int

}

type AvgTradeData = 
| Trade of TradeData
| Block of TradeBlock
```

I'd then make the moving average use a `DList<AvgTradeData>`. (https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/reference/fsharpx-collections-dlist-1.html) The first element in the DList is summed manually if startTime is after the price period and removed from the list once the price period exceeds the endTime. The last elements in the list are kept as `Trade tradeData` until 100 are appended and then all removed from the tail and turned into a `TradeBlock`.